# Working with a Dataset containing multivatiate numerical Timeseries which is highly sparse

Tags: time-series, gaussian-process, multivariate-regression

I am working currently on a private dataset that has a similar structure to MIMIC-III. The dataset has following structure:

*p* Patients,
*e* Examinations,
*t* Timepoints

For every patient there are multivariate timeseries, one timeseries for each exam. The dataset is also highly sparse. For each patient, there is a binary Target *y* (1 or 0).  Target determines if the patient lives or dies. The data collection starts after an operation was performed.

For each patient data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'test 1': {0: 0.0,  1: 2.6,  2: np.nan,  3: 3.3,  4: np.nan},
                        'test 2': {0: np.nan,  1: np.nan,  2: 0.1,  3: 1.1,  4: 1.0},
                        'test 3': {0: 1.0, 1: np.nan, 2: 2.0, 3: np.nan, 4: 1.0}})
df.index.name = "date"
```

Columns are different examinations that the doctor ran, and the index is the day after the operation. It can be assumed, that the data are MNAR (Missing not at random), simply because the doctor decides whether the Exam has to be done, but also decides that none is needed.

I am trying to impute the data and at the same time to predict the outcome, whether the patient dies or lives. The ultimate goal is to create a tool that helps doctors to determine whether the patient lives or dies, and also that show the predicted future values of Examinations, that the model expects.

At first my idea was to run a gaussian process on the dataset, avoiding the imputation as a preprocessing step. I unfortunately couldn't find any method for my usecase.

Then I tried to implement EM, that would approximate the covariance matrix, which I would then use in the gaussian process.

The problem is, I couldn't find a way to implement this for a 3D dataset. So I would ask you, if there are any ideas/implementations that would be applicable in this case.

Comment: What are these data and what are you trying to determine?  All you have told us is what you haven't been able to implement, but you haven't actually told us your problem!

Comment: @whuber I apologize. I did add more information. Is it sufficient or not?

Comment: We still lack sufficient information on the nature of data collection (e.g., would these be panel data?) or on the nature and amount of missing values (if any) or the objective of imputing data.  It's usually better to describe the actual problem you have rather than trying to frame it abstractly, because all too often essential details are inadvertently lost in the abstraction.

Comment: Due to the rules I have to abide by, I can't post the dataset. I am will continue to add as much info as I can.

Comment: It's understood that datasets might be private or too large to post.  You can, however, provide the *descriptions* that are needed to understand and answer your question; and, if it's not too much trouble, you could post a small example of a dataset that looks like yours (with realistic values).

Comment: I tried to create a small "dummy" example of what the data is for ONE patient. The numbers are not representative and only there to visualize the structure of the data.